# Kafka InvalidTopicException for java consumer but not for kafka-console-consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Obviously I have something wrong in my client code, looking for help determining what.

Create the topic:
`kafka-topics --create --topic HELLO --bootstrap-server localhost:29092`

Produce some messages:

```
kafka-console-producer --bootstrap-server localhost:29092 --topic HELLO --property "key.separator=-" -property "parse.key=true"
>1-hello
>2-goodbye
>3-other stuff
```

Consume them all:

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:29092 --topic HELLO --from-beginning
hello
goodbye
other stuff
```

Try the same in Java:

```java
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:29092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "KafkaExampleConsumer");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());

    Consumer<Long, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("HELLO"));

    while(true) {
        ConsumerRecords<Long, String> consumerRecords =
                consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
        consumerRecords.forEach(record -> {
            System.out.printf("Consumer Record:(%d, %s, %d, %d)\n",
                    record.key(), record.value(),
                    record.partition(), record.offset());
        });

        consumer.commitAsync();
    }
```

But the first time I poll it dies with these logs:

```
...
2022-03-29 20:00:32.386  WARN 74696 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-KafkaExampleConsumer-1, groupId=KafkaExampleConsumer] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {"HELLO"=INVALID_TOPIC_EXCEPTION}
2022-03-29 20:00:32.386 ERROR 74696 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-KafkaExampleConsumer-1, groupId=KafkaExampleConsumer] Metadata response reported invalid topics ["HELLO"]
2022-03-29 20:00:32.387  INFO 74696 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-KafkaExampleConsumer-1, groupId=KafkaExampleConsumer] Cluster ID: tyYW3M_ETRePtSOmM4ifJQ
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidTopicException: Invalid topics: ["HELLO"]
```

I wonder if this is something to do with consumer groups/partition count?

Comment: You're getting an INVALID_TOPIC_EXCEPTION on the attempt to subscribe. In https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html they use `Arrays.asList()` rather than `Collections.singletonList()` as the arg to `subscribe()`. I'm not across the differences but perhaps you could try using the `asList()` method instead?

Comment: Thanks for the comment; I tried Arrays.asList("HELLO") and still get the same error.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing; I was getting the errors because I injected the topic from properties, but put literal quotes in the properties file (topic = "HELLO"). So instead of subscribing to HELLO I was subscribing to <quote>HELLO<unquote>.

Comment: It's nice when it's something very straightforward like that.

Comment: Your code shows no property file. This is why we ask for a **verifiable/reproducible** example - [mcve] . Reading a properties file value into a String object should not include quotes, anyway

Answer (score 2):

Found the explanation; here's the error again:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidTopicException: Invalid topics: ["HELLO"]
```

I pulling the topic string from a config file, and used quotes in the config file. So my config reader read the quotes as part of the string value.
I was trying to subscribe to the string "quote-HELLO-unquote" (with literal quotes inside the string), and the quotes are invalid characters.

The error was telling me, I just wasn't seeing it. Here's another invalid topic string with a carat in it but not with literal quotes. Note that the error string does not place quotes around it:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidTopicException: Invalid topics: [hel^lo]
```